# Why is there a size mismatch between structures and unions?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

I have declared a union allocating 4100 bytes to variable "sample_union" and made the same union declaration as part of a structure which is allocating 4104 bytes.

```
union test_size_union {
    struct {
        uint8_t type;
        union {
            uint8_t count;
            uint8_t list;
        };
        uint16_t rc;
        uint16_t arr_value[2048];
    };
    uint64_t first_dword;
}__attribute__((packed)) sample_union ;
```

Placing the above union inside structure is allocating 4104 bytes.

```
struct test_size_struct {
    union {
        struct {
            uint8_t type;
            union {
                uint8_t count;
                uint8_t list;
            };
            uint16_t rc;
            uint16_t arr_value[2048];
        };
        uint64_t first_dword;
    };
}__attribute__((packed)) sample_struct;
```

Well, this is not a project requirement, but I would like to know why compiler is behaving differently for this two declaration.

gcc version: (GCC) 4.9.2, x86_64

Platform: Linux, x86_64

Comment: Note that anonymous structs are not allowed by the C++ standard (GCC does provide it as an extension).

Comment: This what main functions does:
int main(void)
{

    printf("size of sample_union = %d\n", sizeof(sample_union));
    printf("size of sample_struct = %d\n", sizeof(sample_struct));
    return 0;
}

output: 
size of sample_union = 4100
size of sample_struct = 4104

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: The array is of type `uint16_t[2048]`, so takes up 4096 bytes on most machines.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that is 2048 * sizeof(uint16_t) and a bit. Which should be somewhere around 4100 bytes.

Comment: @user50 Don't post multiline code in comments; [edit] your question instead.

Comment: To rephrase my original comment: The structure *inside* the union is not packed.

Comment: bottom line to me is it looks like it *could* align properly, but I'm not surprised that it doesn't...

Comment: Actually, packing a union does make sense in this case.  The unpacked union has some padding so its size is a multiple of 8 (sizeof(uint64_t)).  The packed union doesn't.

Comment: @user2079303 They are allowed by C, since the C11 standard. The question is tagged C as well

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you placed the union inside the struct, you didn't mark the *union* as `packed`.  The unpacked union has a little padding (four bytes) so that its size is a multiple of the size of `uint64_t`.

The packed union doesn't have this padding, so it is smaller.

As a side observation, the anonymous struct inside the union is not marked `packed`.  That happens not to matter in this case, because everything is nicely aligned anyway - but it's something to be aware of.